# How to omit empty json fields using json.decoder

Tags: go

I try to understand why both functions return the same output.
As far as I understood, the point of omit empty is to not add that key to the result struct.

I wrote this example, I was expecting the first output not to have the "Empty" key, but for some reason its value still shows as 0.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type agentOmitEmpty struct {
    Alias   string `json:"Alias,omitempty"`
    Skilled bool   `json:"Skilled,omitempty"`
    FinID   int32  `json:"FinId,omitempty"`
    Empty   int    `json:"Empty,omitempty"`
}

type agent struct {
    Alias   string `json:"Alias"`
    Skilled bool   `json:"Skilled"`
    FinID   int32  `json:"FinId"`
    Empty   int    `json:"Empty"`
}

func main() {
    jsonString := `{
        "Alias":"Robert",
        "Skilled":true,
        "FinId":12345
    }`

    fmt.Printf("output with omit emtpy: %v\n", withEmpty(strings.NewReader(jsonString)))
    // output with omit emtpy: {Robert true 12345 0}

    fmt.Printf("output regular: %v\n", withoutEmpty(strings.NewReader(jsonString)))
    // output without omit: {Robert true 12345 0}
}

func withEmpty(r *strings.Reader) agentOmitEmpty {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(r)
    body := agentOmitEmpty{}
    err := dec.Decode(&body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return body
}

func withoutEmpty(r *strings.Reader) agent {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(r)
    body := agent{}
    err := dec.Decode(&body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return body
}
```

Comment: The `json:"Alias,omitempty"` tag and option is for the `encoding/json` package. The `fmt` package doesn't care about that, it prints all fields.

Comment: How about other packages, like gorm for example.  Will it try to insert 0 for that key into the database?

Comment: Further, `omitempty` is only useful for JSON _encoding_. It has no effect at all for decoding.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. If someone wants to write an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define Empty as `*int` so it will be replaced with nil when there is no value. Then it will not be saved in the database.

Comment: ok thanks,  would I need to dereference the pointer then, If I want to insert it with gorm?

Comment: I'm not familiar with gorm but I think it should handle pointers well.

Comment: If you want to control what gorm does, you'll need to use its tags. It doesn't care about `json` tags, which are for the json package.